# List alphabetically in Windows Explorer, with folders mixed with files?

Tags: windows-explorer

Previously when opening Windows explorer, it would come up as below:

```
Key
Folders : UPPERCASE
documents : LOWERCASE
```

Example A:

- APPLES
- apple 1
- apple 2
- BANANAS
- banana 1
- banana 2
- CARROT
- carrot 1
- carrot 2

Etc, etc, all types of files (whether they be folders or documents) showed alphabetically.

Now, they show like below:

Example B.

- APPLES
- BANANAS
- CARROTS
- apple 1
- apple 2
- banana 1
- banana 2
- carrot 1
- carrot 2

Sorting the folders alphabetically then the documents alphabetically. 
How do I get it back to example A?

Comment: iirc, Windows has always had this irritating folder/file default sort order - but I'm keen to find a solution too, even if it's a 3rd party one.

Comment: I can't even remember if Explorer in Windows 95 would do what you're asking, but I'm pretty sure that it's predecessor, File Manager would.  Are you sure you were using stock Windows Explorer when it worked previously, or were you using some other replacement?  I would love to have an option in Explorer to do this, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with a 3rd party file browser: http://www.zabkat.com/x2lite.htm

How to enable within x2lite:

- right click on the header of the *columns* (Name, Extension, Size, Attributes,...) and then *select columns* (Or just hit ALT+K)
- select the additional column **8.3 Name** and add it to your used columns.
- sort the list of files by the **8.3 Name** instead of the regular *Name* column

Comment: Can't say I'm *hugely* happy with either solution, but it does indeed work. The Bounty is yours.

Comment: **xplorer²** was able to solve this issue. Anyway I'm still interested in doing this in the Windows explorer.

Just wrote a German Tutorial about this and xplorer² (http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/03/08/windows-explorer-sortierung-f%C3%BCr-ordner-und-dateien-mit-xplorer%C2%B2/). It should be easy to understand also for non-Germans. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is also a *partial* solution within Windows explorer itself:

- right-click into the folder, *group by **Name***
- if you like, you can then select a *sort by **Name***

This will give you intermixed folders and files, but will insert some separators that group by letters.

Source (also describes how to make this permanent):
[Windows Explorer sorts files and folders separately](https://superuser.com/questions/204016/windows-7-windows-explorer-sorts-files-and-folders-separately)

Comment: This does not work for me. It groups files and folders into a few groups based on the first letters in the filenames, but within each group it still separates all the folders from all the files.