# Sorting folder and file shortcuts by "Date Modified" in Windows 7 is broken

Tags: windows-7, sorting, file-shortcut

How can I get Windows to sort folders when you click on the "Data modified" column header?

It is not, when shortcut folders and files are in the list.  How can I fix this, or is this a bug in Windows?

[image]

Microsoft, this is embarrassing.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/204016/windows-explorer-sorts-files-and-folders-separately

Comment: Wait, are you asking for folders and files to be sorted together, rather than folders first, or are you saying the folders aren't being sorted at all?

Comment: What do you think **should** be the sorting order?

Comment: @David, look at the last file in the list.  See how it's 7/26.  The middle files are 7/27, and the shortcuts are 7/17.  I clicked the header before making this screen shot.

Comment: @MacGyver It sorts the shortcuts first, then the folders.

Comment: @David, yes it does.  That's what the feature is apparently, but it doesn't make any logical sense it would do that.  I guess it would be considered an enhancement to Microsoft, but most would consider it a bug.

Comment: @MacGyver Yeah, I use xyplorer. It can be configured to sort folders separately or not.